# Bootstrap 2.3.2 - Right-align a Button with an Input inside of a form-horizontal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm having trouble styling the following form using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2

I can't seem to right-align the button with the other labels. Also, I can't get the last textbox to be in line with the button.

This is the form I have so far: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisauret/wp8pW/)

```
<form class="form-horizontal">

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputFirstname">First name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputFirstname" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputSurname">Surname</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputSurname" placeholder="Surname">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Browse</button>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputSomeText" placeholder="Some text">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

This is the end result which I trying to achieve:[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last `control-group` and also add `margin-top:-5px;` to the button (shown below via class `label-btn`):

HTML for last `control-group`:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><button class="btn btn-primary inline label-btn">Browse</button></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputSomeText" placeholder="Some text">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.label-btn {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp8pW/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Change last control-group to this

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">
            <button class="btn btn-primary inline">Browse</button>
        </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputSomeText" placeholder="Some text">
        </div>
    </div>
```